# high z-index put element in front of others, but let click on them

Tags: css, angular, z-index

In my angular project I added `ngx-loading-bar` from [aitboudad/ngx-loading-bar](https://github.com/aitboudad/ngx-loading-bar), (I installed the http-client package), this is my app.component.html:

```html
<div class="main-comp">
    <ngx-loading-bar [color]="'#74ffff'" [includeSpinner]="false" [height]="'3px'" ></ngx-loading-bar>

    <header>
       ...header content...
    </header>
    <main id="main-content">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </main>
    <footer id="footer-content">
      ...footer content...
    </footer>
</div>
```

Now I need to add a black full screen element to block the user to press any buttons while the loader appears. I used the following scss code:

```scss
::ng-deep{
    .ngx-bar{
        z-index: 100;
        &::after{
            content: "";
            display: block;
            width: 100vw;
            height: 100vh;
            background-color: #00000066;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }
    }
}
```

this indeed shows half opacity black div in front of all elements in the screen, but unfortunately - this doesn't prevent the click on elements! Even when I changed the color to totaly `black` or any non-transparent color - I still see the cursor changing to pointer and clicking when it's so - cause actions and http requests.

what is the problem? I tried to give high z-index, and change the positions fron `fixed` to `absolute` - didn't help. I also suspected that it might be pseudo element issue, so I deleted the `::after` and tried to give full size to the loader div itself - same result!

I will be greatfull for any advice!

Comment: Check if `pointer-events: none;` is used by the loading bar.

Comment: You could try setting the div CSS attribute `pointer-events: none;`

Comment: @BraianPita, @JakubKotrs -  I put `pointer-events: none` on the :after and all its parents, no change

Comment: @ayala I would recommend you wrap your `ngx-loading-bar` component on a div and create a class for it. Then just move all the CSS you shared into that class (no :after selector).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making my comment into an answer, I think the problem was the `:after` selector is not working as you intended. You can learn more about the after selector [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after)

Basically, to achieve your desired result, you can wrap the `ngx-loading-bar` component on a div and set the styling with a class. (You can use the `has()` function for a pure CSS solution. It will style the div only when the loader line appears inside of it)

CSS

```
.loadbar-bg:has(div) {
  display: block;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #00000066;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="main-comp">
    <div class="loadbar-bg" >
        <ngx-loading-bar [color]="'#74ffff'" [includeSpinner]="false" [height]="'3px'" ></ngx-loading-bar>
    </div>

    <header>
       ...header content...
    </header>
    <main id="main-content">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </main>
    <footer id="footer-content">
      ...footer content...
    </footer>
</div>
```